# Are commands in a pipeline run simultaneously?

Tags: pipe

In a pipeline such as `command1 | command2`,

- are the commands run simultaneously (i.e. have the same lifetime), or
- command2 starts to run at the time command1 exits, or
- something else?

My question arises when I heard that the commands' processes form a process group. If they don't have the same lifetime, isn't the process group of the commands' processes meaningless?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The processes are *started* at the same time, and will run concurrently, but they don't have to *stop* at the same time. The shell will consider the entire pipeline to have terminated (and display a new prompt) when *both* processes have terminated.

If `command2` ends before `command1` does (or closes its standard input stream), and `command1` then attempts to write output, there's nowhere for that output to go. Then `command1` will receive a `SIGPIPE` signal, whose default action is to abort `command1`. But `command1` itself can override this default such that it gets to continue running instead. In that case its attempts to write output will produce an ordinary I/O error (`EPIPE`) which it can react to however it wants.

Answer (score 1):

"|"` AKA,  "Pipes"....pipes let you use the output of a program as the input of another one" . So if let's say we do this:

```
user$ cat SHAHashing.java | grep main
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception
```

as you can see the cat executed first displaying the page's contents "THE OUTPUT" , and then grep for the string main .

Now lets assume I mistyped `CAT` like this:

```
user$ cats SHAHashing.java | grep main
-bash: cats: command not found
```

No output "wrong command" , grep will execute but with nothing to do  .hence .... cats causeed the first command to terminate  with status "exit 1".

Comment: `grep` does execute in the second example too. It just doesn't have much to do, because its input ends immediately. You can observe this by doing, e.g. `cats and dogs | echo hello`, which _will_ output `hello`, while complaining that there are no cats. The error message about the missing cats is being written to the first command's _standard error_ stream, which is _not_ redirected by default. But try `cats and dogs 2>&1 | tr a u`